# How can dreams be in sync with real world sounds?

Tags: dreams

Some events in my dreams use the sounds from my (real world) surroundings.

I don't understand **how** because it would mean my brain would **know what sounds will happen before they happen**. That obviously doesn't seem right.

##### Example:

In a dream, I look at a tree. The tree falls down. When it hits the ground, it makes the sound of thunder, which wakes me up. As I'm awake I still hear the rumble of the thunder which happened for real.

How could my dream **synchronize** the tree hitting the ground with the real sound of thunder?

---

It seems this phenomenon happens to multiple people. Here are a few external examples.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Dreams/comments/21bt5n/how_can_my_dreams_predict_waking_noise/
- https://www.quora.com/How-does-our-brain-instantly-create-a-reason-for-an-external-sound-when-we-are-dreaming

Some people from those discussions suggest that *dream-time* happens faster than *real-time*.

**Is there any research about this phenomenon?**

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21641/7604